# Can we apply squeeze in that way?

Tags: calculus

Claim:
if $a_n\leq b_n\leq c_n$ for all $n\in \mathbb{N}$ and  $\displaystyle\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty} a_n,\displaystyle\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty} c_n$ are convergent then$\displaystyle\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty} b_n$ is convergent.

I think it is a wrong statement but I could not find any counterexample.

If you find a counterexample or prove it,I would be thankful.

Comment: Have you tried proving this with the Algebraic Limit Theorems for Series and the Order Limit Theorems?

Comment: @spitfiredd: No,I have not.

Comment: I say give that a shot and see what you get, it shouldn't be too difficult.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\sum_{i=k}^l a_i \le  \sum_{i=k}^l b_i \le \sum_{i=k}^l c_i$$
This implies that
$$|\sum_{i=k}^l b_i| \le\max \{ |\sum_{i=k}^l a_i|, |\sum_{i=k}^l c_i|\}$$
Now $\sum a_i$, $\sum c_i$ exist, hence  and right term becomes arbitrarily small  (Cauchy-criterion),  if $k,l$  are chosen large enough, hence the partial sums $B_k:=\sum_0^k b_i$ are Cauchy as well.

Comment: +1 ; so to recap, the left and right term become arbitrarily small (cauchy's criterion) because they converge, so the sum in the middle must too become arbitrarily small; this implies (again with cauchy criterion) that $\sum b_n$ converges; right?

Comment: @thomas: if $A_i\leq B_i\leq C_i$ can we say that $|A_i-A_j|\leq |B_i-B_j|\leq |C_i-C_j|$ ?? or you mean something else?

Comment: @mesel No. But you have a bound from below and above through terms which become small in absolute value. So $|B_i -B_j|$ is less than the $\max$ of the absolute values.

Comment: @Ant: yes, that's correct.

Comment: I am sorry but I did not get the point why $B_i$ is cauchy sequence.

Comment: @mesel I'll edit my answer.

Comment: @Thomas: right hand side need not be arbitrary small,if you mean $max\{|A_i|,|C_i|\}$ ?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/13627/discussion-between-thomas-and-mesel)